# Using extern to include files in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, include, extern

How this works in C or C++?

```
extern "C" {
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fd_config.h>
#include <ut_trace.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't work in C. `extern "C"` is a C++ thing; it tells the compiler to treat whatever follows as if it were C, to avoid name mangling.

Comment: this code is used in C++. do you want to know how this code is compiled by gcc?

Comment: Yes I want to know how it works in C++

Comment: This has been asked several times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extern

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard does not specify how compilers should name the symbols in their object files (for instance, `Foo::bar()` might end up as `__clsFoo_fncBar` or some gobbledygook). The C standard does, and it is almost always different from how C++ compilers do it (C doesn't have to deal with classes, namespaces, overloading, etc.).

As a result, when you are linking against an object file that was output by a C compiler, you have to tell your C++ compiler to look for symbols with names that correspond to the C standard. You are essentially putting it in "C mode." This is what the `"C"` part of `extern "C"` does.

(Alternatively, you might also be declaring functions or variables that could be used by an external C object file. In this case, it means export those symbols the C way.)

Comment: The C++ naming is known as "name mangling".  This is done because overloading allows multiple functions with the same name, and the linker needs to distinguish 'Foo::bar()' from 'Foo::bar(int i)' and 'Foo::bar(double a, float b)'.  The 'mangled' prefix or suffix is derived from the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

If your Project has C and C++ source files and you need to build as a whole( C files calls some functions in C++ files) ,so we need to protect the C file function calls and symbols by declaring as in C++ files by

extern "C"
{ 
   /*symbols used in c files*/
   uint8 GetCurrentthreadState(HANDLE ThreadId)

}

Then the C++ complier generate compilation output which is same as that of C complier for the above declared functions and symbols.So on linking time , the compiler can easily link the C and C++ defined symbols with out any link error.

So my opinion is not needed to give the **#ifdef __cplusplus** check on compilation.
Because we need to protect the symbols in c++ files right?  Also C++ files can be compiled by C++ compiler only right?

/renjith g

Comment: The #ifdef __cplusplus guards are useful if you have the declarations in a header file that may be included by both C and C++ programs. This happens very often when you have a mixed C/C++ project or you are writing a library.

Comment: no , it is not at all necessary to check #ifdef __cplusplus macro in header files , if you are using a native C++ compiler.The extern "C" {} usage is enough for the same.

/renjith g

Answer (score 1):

It will not work, you need to add the cplusplus preprocessor...

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// your code


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

EDIT:

In C++, the name will be treated like in C which mean that there will be no mangle name. It allows to make the difference between two C++ different function with different argument type/number or a different namespace in a library (for library purpose libname.so, libname.a). If the name is mangled, the C program will not be able to recognize it

```
eg:
int myfction()
void myfunction(int)
void myfunction(int, char)

C library:   myfction

C++ library: int_myction (it depend on your compiler)
C++ library: int_myction_int (it depend on your compiler)
C++ library: int_myction_int_char (it depend on your compiler)
// ... which is not allowed in C program
```

Answer (score 0):

Every C++ Compiler needs to support the extern "C" linkage.
The code in such block could be legacy code written in C for a certain functionality, which is required for the current program.

How this is implemented is mostly compiler dependent, However I heard that many Compilers disable the name mangling and change the calling convention.